# How to filter the price with the input type range in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, jquery-ui

I want to filter the price with the input type range.

Can anyone help me to solve my problem with filtering? I'm trying to filter the product's price using the input range slider.

All I want is a filter for my data to show all my wine above the value that I have to put in my input range. What I should write in my own Laravel?

blade

```
<form action="">
    <div class="mb-3">
        <input type="hidden" name="min" value="" id="min">
        <input type="hidden" name="max" value="" id="max">
        <label for="price" class="form-label">price</label>
        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" id="min" name="min" aria-label="min" readonly class="border-0 text-purple fw-bold form-control mb-3">
            <input type="text" id="max" name="max" aria-label="max" readonly class="border-0 text-purple fw-bold form-control mb-3">
        </div>
        <div id="slider-range"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="mb-3">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-dark">filter</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

script

```
<script src="{{ asset('themes/js/jquery-ui.min.js') }}"></script>
<script>
    $(function() {
        let max = 1000000;
        let min = 1;
        $("#slider-range").slider({
            range: true,
            max: max,
            min: min,
            values: [min, max],
            slide: function(event, ui) {
                $("#min").val(ui.values[0]).trigger('change');
                $("#max").val(ui.values[1]).trigger('change');
            }
        });
        $("#min").val($("#slider-range").slider("values", 0));
        $("#max").val($("#slider-range").slider("values", 1));
    });
</script>
```

Controller

```
public function single(Category $category = null)
{
    $categories = Category::query()->where('type', 'product')
        ->whereNotIn('parent_id', [0])
        ->get();
    if (is_null($category)) {
        $products = collect([]);
    } else {
        $query = $category->products()->where('status', 1);
        if (request()->has('title')) {
            $query = $query->where('title', 'LIKE', '%' . request()->input('title') . '%');
        }
        $validator = Validator::make(request()->all(), [
            'min' => 'required|integer',
            'max' => 'required|integer'
        ]);
        if ($validator->passes()) {
            $query = $query->getQuery()->whereBetween('price', [
                request('min'),
                request('max')
            ]);
        }
        $products = $query->get();
    }
    $max = (int) Product::query()->max('price');
    $min = (int) Product::query()->min('price');
    return view('Home.contents.category', compact('category','products', 'categories', 'min', 'max'));
}
```

I see this in the address bar.

> localhost:8000/category/computer?min=1&max=1000000&min=&max=